# Determining domain names based on IP address?

Tags: ip

A NOOB question - I'm accessing internal development environment resources:

```
http://10.1.2.3:8080/xyz
http://localhost:8080/xyz
```

I'm trying to configure an iOS [security exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33306373/47281) which requires a domain name (not IP I believe).  How do you determine the domains?

We have these dev resources on servers running different OS's: OSX, Windows 7, and Solaris.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 (e.g. DNS) are explicitly off-topic here. You can try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can do a reverse DNS lookup:

dig -x a.b.c.d

But I'm assuming the first address is inside your organization, so it probably has the same domain as you. localhost is your computer.